# How to get my Jquery mouse up function to work

Tags: jquery, html, mousedown, mouseup

I am trying to have a div on mouse down change style and on the mouseup anywhere on the page have the div revert to its initial state. Is there an error with my code. How do I cause all the divs to revert to the original status using the mouseup function anywhere on the page. I am aware of (this) function but is there an (anywhere) function.

```js
$(".div1").mousedown(function(evt) {
  $(this).css({
    "height": "200px",
    "width": "400px",
    "background-color": "red",
    "color": "green",
    "text-align": "right",
  }).html("Lynch");
});


$(document).mouseup(function(evt) {
  $('div').css({
    "height": "100px",
    "width": "200px",
    "background-color": "green",
    "color": "red",
    "text-align": "left",
  }).html("Chris");
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  color: red;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <h3>
    Chris
  </h3>
</div>

<div class="div1">
  <h3>
    Chris
  </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
  <h3>
    Chris
  </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
  <h3>
    Chris
  </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
  <h3>
    Chris
  </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
  <h3>
    Chris
  </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
  <h3 Chris </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
  <h3>
    Chris
  </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
  <h3>
    Chris
  </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
  <h3>
    Chris
  </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Bind mouse up to the document instead of the div but to be more precise, you should probably remember the trigger element and check for it before doing any code on mouse up. This way you won't be firing useless code every time a mouse clicks anywhere

Comment: I change the ('.div1') to (document) and the (this) to ('div') That sound about right?

Comment: sounds right, you just need to try it and see if it works

Comment: Any chance you can check the upload out? It is being kind of funny. hcc-computerscience.com/lynch/page1.html this i the site. When I click anywhere all the divs become one long column. I cannot figure out what the mistake is

Comment: I have added an answer and updated your question with your page's code

Answer (score 0):

There was a small issue or typo in your page, there was a missing closing tag for one of the `h3`s.

The spacing issue you are seeing is because in your original markup, you have a `h3` in every div but after mouseup (h3 has a default margin on it), you modify the content of each div to plain text of `Chris`. In the code below, I have added a margin bottom to the divs so that the space will always be there and you could remove the h3 from the original mark if you want - probably a good idea so you have consistent content before and after the mouse event.

I have also put your mousedown styles into a class so all you need to do is addd/remove this class depending on mouse event. It's cleaner code and more efficient

```js
$(".div1").mousedown(function(evt) {
  $(this).addClass("down").html("Lynch");
});


$(document).mouseup(function(evt) {
  $('div').removeClass("down").html("Chris");
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  color: red;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.div1.down {
  background-color: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  color: green;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <h3>
    Chris
  </h3>
</div>

<div class="div1">
  <h3>
    Chris
  </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
  <h3>
    Chris
  </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
  <h3>
    Chris
  </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
  <h3>
    Chris
  </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
  <h3>
    Chris
  </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
  <h3> Chris </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
  <h3>
    Chris
  </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
  <h3>
    Chris
  </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
  <h3>
    Chris
  </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

About the new issue you have (one column), the problem comes from the  elements.

elements have a default margin which can have an effect on the parents siblings, that's why you have margin at page load.

But on mouse up or down, you directly set the html content of the divs, removing the  elements at the same time, which makes the margin to disappear !